# Get text without certain element included using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this table below. And I want to get the text inside td.am-receipt-price but without getting the span text included.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="am-receipt-price">
        <span class="am-receipt-discounted-price"><del>price 1</del></span>
        price 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`console.log ( $(".am-receipt-price").text() )` would also return the text inside the span. I have tried `.remove("span")` but it wont work.

Am I missing any selector that I have not tried yet? thanks in advance.

Comment: Agree with @Drdilyor, it looks like the accepted answer to the question they linked should work pretty well for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add another element around the target node and use a selector to retrieve it.

Assuming you cannot amend the HTML, then you can use `contents()` and `filter()` on the parent `td` to target the node and read its `textContent`.

```js
let $td = $('.am-receipt-price');
let nodes = $td.contents().filter((i, n) => n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && n.textContent.trim() !== '');

console.log(nodes[0].textContent.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="am-receipt-price">
        <span class="am-receipt-discounted-price">
          <del>price 1</del>
        </span> 
        price 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I also found that this script also works
$(this) .clone()
   .children()
   .remove()
   .end()
   .text();

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the already provided `.contents()` solution (if you need/want an alternative) is to use `.clone()` and `.remove()`, where you copy the html into a variable then you can do what you want with it without changing the original.

```js
var price = $("td.am-receipt-price").clone();
price.find("span").remove();
console.log(price.text().trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="am-receipt-price">
        <span class="am-receipt-discounted-price">
          <del>price 1</del>
        </span> 
        price 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It may be that your `.remove("span")` just had the wrong syntax:

```
$("td.am-receipt-price").find("span").remove()
```

would change the original DOM nodes.